# Im trying to navigate to my shipping page but i keep getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce, mern

This is the error message

```
react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'search')
at Login (Login.js:21:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

This is my code

my Login.js

```
const Login = ({ history, location }) => {

const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

const alert = useAlert();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const { isAuthenticated, error, loading } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

const navigate = useNavigate();
// navigate('/')



useEffect(() => {

    if (isAuthenticated) {
        navigate(redirect)
    }

    if (error) {
        alert.error(error);
        dispatch(clearErrors());
    }

}, [dispatch, alert, isAuthenticated, error, navigate, redirect])


const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password))
}

return ()} export default Login
```

the error seems to be coming from my "location.search" because in my vscode that part is line 21. Has there been any recent change in documentation?

Comment: location is undefined. Where is the Login component being rendered? Is location being passed into the Login component there? Is location being passed into the Login component in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where `location` & `history` props come from?
If your are using hooks, I assume this should not come from props, but from hooks

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  ...
}
```